# Error while inserting in to a Mysql table which contain fields "from" and "to"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I tried to insert into a table in Mysql with the following fields direction, from, to, message, I got the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, message) VALUES ( 'outgoing','FROM_NUMBER','TO_NUMBER','asas')'

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO corporate.sms (direction, from, to, message) VALUES ( 'outgoing','FROM_NUMBER','TO_NUMBER','test message');
```

Is there any other way to do the insertion without changing the column names?

Comment: use backticks arround keyword if you use them as fieldnames: **INSERT INTO corporate.sms (`direction`, `from`, `to`, `message`) VALUES ( 'outgoing','FROM_NUMBER','TO_NUMBER','test message');**

ups: you cant see them ins this comment use this as Backtick : `

Answer (score 1):

Since field name such as 'from' and 'to' is reserved by MySQL's SQL syntax,
you need to wrap those field names by ` ( backquote ).

So your SQL will be

```
INSERT INTO corporate.sms (direction, `from`, `to`, message) VALUES ( 'outgoing','FROM_NUMBER','TO_NUMBER','test message');
```

Answer (score 1):

`from` and `to` are reserved keywords in SQL.

The solution is quite simple. Just encapsulate the `from` and `to` columns in your query between two Grave Accents(<kbd>``</kbd>), which is the key above `Tab` in your keyboard. That way, SQL Parser distinguishes the column names with reserved keywords and performs the insertion.

The query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO corporate.sms (direction, `from`, `to`, message) VALUES ( 'outgoing','FROM_NUMBER','TO_NUMBER','test message');
```